# NoSuchMethodError while creating Storage object of Google Storage (Java)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I get the following error trying to create a Storage element -

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions.newBuilder()Lcom/google/cloud/storage/StorageOptions$Builder;

using -

```
 AuthCredentials.ServiceAccountAuthCredentials serviceAccountAuthCredentials = AuthCredentials.createForJson(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("abc.json"));
 ServiceAccountCredentials serviceAccountCredentials = serviceAccountAuthCredentials.credentials();
 Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(serviceAccountCredentials).build().getService();
```

The same code works in another application.
Can someone help me as to what can be going wrong with this application.

My pom.xml looks like -

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>

<groupId>com.example.abc</groupId>
<artifactId>abc</artifactId>

<properties>
    <appengine.app.version>1</appengine.app.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<prerequisites>
    <maven>3.5.1</maven>
</prerequisites>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>24.0-jre</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.62</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/gcloud-java-storage -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>gcloud-java-storage</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-bom</artifactId>
        <version>0.34.0-alpha</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--causes exception on removal-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-atom</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
        <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180130</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>20041228.180559</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- causes exception on removal-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.5</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
        <version>v3-rev99-1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <!-- for hot reload of the web application-->
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                        <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                <webResources>
                    <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.60</version>
            <configuration>
                <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>



            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!--<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <includes>
                                <include>com.google.guava:*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </artifactSet>
                        <minimizeJar>false</minimizeJar>
                        <relocations>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>com.google.common</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>repackaged.com.google.common</shadedPattern>
                            </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>-->
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I'd like to reproduce your issue but I am missing a few pieces here. Can you  provide a full minimum sample to reproduce or at least the rest of the pom and the steps you follow to deploy/run the app? Btw, is the error showing up  only after deployment or also locally?

Comment: The pom is complete. I was using the same code in another application and it was working fine but it is giving errors in this new application. (I haven't tried it locally for this reason.)

Comment: Thanks for answering but, it only shows the dependencies section. [This](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/blob/master/helloworld-servlet/pom.xml) is how a complete pom looks like. May I also have the command you use to deploy your app? (of course, blank out your projectID or other identifiable info)

Comment: Hey, I have updated the pom. I am using maven appengine:update to deploy the app

Comment: Hi Gaurav, I've done some tests by combining in various forms your pom with the [Java8-helloworld sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/helloworld) and your code runs fine with all configurations. Unfortunately, I've run out of ideas so, if you are able to build a minimum (but full) sample that allows to reproduce the issue, I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: I have a rest service. You can try the following code -

Comment: @Path("checkStorage")
    @GET
    public Response checkStorage() {
        try {
           AuthCredentials.ServiceAccountAuthCredentials auth = AuthCredentials.createForJson(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("abc.json"));
                    ServiceAccountCredentials sa = auth.credentials();
                    Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
                            .setCredentials(sa)
                            .build()
                            .getService();
                                
        }catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

Comment: Unfortunately, the three lines in the original post plus a try-catch inside an annotated method, is far from being a full minimum sample that reproduces your issue. A full sample should look like [Java8-helloworld](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/helloworld) and be runnable by anyone by just specifying the project and using "mvn appengine:update"

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete example. You can download the sample from 
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/dbf2681892d2823fcb9d04c028139ab920180302120925/4f0b77

Comment: Hi Gaurav, were you able to get passed this issue? I know it's a year later, but want to confirm. If you still have the full sample that would be helpful as well. It has since expired.

Answer (score 0):

Without having dug much into the root cause (which seems to be 
 jersey's com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory use of reflection ending up with a wrong version of the com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions class)

The only workaround I've found so far is to upgrade google-cloud-storage version from 1.16.0 to 1.19.0

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
   <version>1.19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Let me know if that helps and, thanks for sharing the full sample.

Comment: Upgrading google-cloud-storage version to 1.19.0 is giving the same error. Let me know if you have changed any other dependency version.

Comment: This is extremely weird. I had removed two elements before upgrading google-cloud-storage: One was "google-cloud-bom" and the other "versions-maven-plugin" because it gives me an unrelated warning that I did not want to deal with. I have just went back to your original pom (with only changing my project and bucket) I am unable to reproduce the issue. :-(